# Load QWidget with plot into Mainwindow

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

I’m trying to load a QWidget UI (TestWidget.ui) into a MainWindow. The QWidget contains another QWidget which is promoted to a pyqtgraph PlotWidget. I’ve used the qtdesigner to create the TestWidget.ui. So far it works except my PlotWidget is not shown at all. Does anyone have an advice?
Here is my code:

```python
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setCentralWidget(TestWidget())

class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.ui = loader.load('TestWidget.ui', self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You could just use `setCentralWidget()` with the result of QUiLoader. Or do you actually need a class for it?

Comment: I probably could modify my code to work like this but the problem remains the same.

Comment: No, if you move the loader in the `__init__` of `MainWindow` and then do `self.setCentralWidget(self.ui)`, it will work (assuming that the widget has been properly promoted).

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. What does properly promoted mean? I promoted it like it is mentioned here: https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyside6-embed-pyqtgraph-custom-widgets/ . I removed the second class and tried to move the loader to my MainWindow. However my promoted QWidget is still recognized as QWidget and not as PlotWidget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by deleting the TestWidget class and moving the loader in the **init** of MainWindow.
Also added `loader.registerCustomWidget(PlotWidget)` between `loader = QUiLoader()` and `self.ui = loader.load('TestWidget.ui', self)` to finally make it work.